# Need to set a maximum (100) and minimum (0), for this average test result program

Tags: java

Need to set a maximum (100) and minimum (0), for this average test result program. I understand that i would need to use '<' and'>' somewhere within my work however i am not sure how/where

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ExamResults {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);          
        System.out.println("Enter the 5 exam results");
        double ExamResult1 = 0.0;
        ExamResult1 = Double.parseDouble(keyboard.nextLine());
        double ExamResult2 = 0.0;
        ExamResult2 = Double.parseDouble(keyboard.nextLine());
        double ExamResult3 = 0.0;
        ExamResult3 = Double.parseDouble(keyboard.nextLine());
        double ExamResult4 = 0.0;
        ExamResult4 = Double.parseDouble(keyboard.nextLine());
        double ExamResult5 = 0.0;
        ExamResult5 = Double.parseDouble(keyboard.nextLine());
        double averageScore;                                    
        averageScore = ((ExamResult1 + ExamResult2 + ExamResult3 + ExamResult4 + ExamResult5)/5);
        System.out.println("The average Score is" + averageScore);
    }
}
```

Comment: you want every input to be checked for the max and min or only the calculated average?

Comment: Why `double ExamResult1 = 0.0;  ExamResult1 = Double.parseDouble(keyboard.nextLine());` instead of `double ExamResult1 = keyboard.nextDouble();`? (question applies to all `ExamResultX`)

Comment: @Pshemo They would give you the same result, so it doesn't really matter which one you choose

Comment: @TamásF Well, we gain nothing except code readability, which IMO is enough reason to use `nextDouble` over what is in code now.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like:

```
double min = Math.min(Math.min(ExamResult1, ExamResult2), ExamResult3);//similarly for others
double max = Math.max(Math.max(ExamResult1, ExamResult2), ExamResult3);//similarly for others
```

Answer (score 0):

I would do this:

```
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);          
    System.out.println("Enter the 5 exam results");
    double[] examResults = new double[5];
    double total = 0.0;
    for (int i = 0; i < examResults.length; i++)
    {
        double value = Double.parseDouble(keyboard.nextLine());

        while (value < 0 || value  > 100)
        {
             System.out.println("Invalid score, try again");
             value = Double.parseDouble(keyboard.nextLine());
        }
        examResults[i] = value;
        total += value;
    }
    double averageScore;                                    
    averageScore = total / examResults.length;
    System.out.println("The average Score is" + averageScore);
```